# get polynom representation for lagrangian interpolation

Tags: f#

How can I represent an incomplete mathematical function?

I need to do something like `(x - constant)` then

```
(x - constant)*(x - another) => (x^2 - x * constant - x * another + constant * another)
```

and so on.

I'm trying to make a program to do Lagrangian interpolation (finding a function for some points)
so I need to make a function that I can see (print, or something), from a set of known values.
sorry if confusing.

Comment: what do you mean with incomplete? Partial? I know what interpolation is and stuff but I really don't know what the question is - are you asking how you can visualize a function (like printing it's graph)? Or is the question how you can represent a function given by some points?

Comment: @CarstenKönig representing the function of the given points. and then be able to visualize the resulting function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to implement the Lagrange Interpolation as discussed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html)

### getting a function that interpolates values:

then this is the direct translation into F#:

```
let LagrangeInterpol (points : (Double*Double)[]) x =
    let indizes = [0..points.Length-1]
    let p j = 
        indizes
        |> List.map (fun k -> 
            if k <> j 
            then (x - fst points.[k]) 
                  / (fst points.[j] - fst points.[k]) 
            else 1.0)
        |> List.fold (*) 1.0 
    indizes |> List.sumBy (fun j -> p j * snd points.[j])
```

#### examples

Here is a simple test-session:

```
> let points = [|0.0,0.0; 1.0,2.0; 2.0,3.0|];;
val points : (float * float) [] = [|(0.0, 0.0); (1.0, 2.0); (2.0, 3.0)|]

> let f = LagrangeInterpol points;;
val f : (Double -> float)

> f 0.0;;
val it : float = 0.0

> f 1.0;;
val it : float = 2.0

> f 2.0;;
val it : float = 3.0
```

So I hope I did not make any major mistake.

Please note that I made no efford to do any performance optimizations here - this should be sufficent to draw a graph or get a few values in between.

### getting a representation of the polynom

This is a bit more trickier - you can either try to come up with the combinatorical formulas for the  coefficients or (like me here) be mathematical lazy and just implement a Polynom-Type with just enough operators:

```
type Polynom = 
    Poly of float list with
    override p.ToString () =
        match p with
        | Poly coefs -> 
            System.String.Join (" + ", coefs |> List.mapi (fun i c -> sprintf "%AX^%d" c i))
    static member Const c = Poly [c]
    static member Zero = Polynom.Const 0.0
    static member One = Polynom.Const 1.0
    static member X = Poly [0.0; 1.0]
    static member (+) (Poly cs1, Poly cs2) =
        let m = max (List.length cs1) (List.length cs2)
        List.zip (ofLen m cs1) (ofLen m cs2)
        |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a+b)
        |> Poly
    static member (-) (Poly cs1, Poly cs2) =
        let m = max (List.length cs1) (List.length cs2)
        List.zip (ofLen m cs1) (ofLen m cs2)
        |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a-b)
        |> Poly
    static member (*) (f : float, Poly cs2) : Polynom =
        cs2
        |> List.map (fun c -> f * c)
        |> Poly
    static member private shift n (Poly cs) =
        List.replicate n 0.0 @ cs |> Poly
    static member (*) (Poly cs1, p2 : Polynom) : Polynom =
        cs1
        |> List.mapi (fun i c -> Polynom.shift i (c * p2))
        |> List.sum
    static member (/) (Poly cs1, f : float) : Polynom =
        cs1
        |> List.map (fun c -> c / f)
        |> Poly
```

Here I just use a list of `float`s to represent the coefficients of a polynom (so `X^2 + 2X + 3` is `Poly [3.0; 2.0; 1.0]` note that the `i`th coefficient is the one at `X^i`.

Having this we can use almost the same function as before:

```
let getPolynom (points : (float * float)[]) =
    let indizes = [0..points.Length-1]
    let p j = 
        indizes
        |> List.map (fun k -> 
            if k <> j 
            then (Polynom.X - Polynom.Const (fst points.[k]))
                  / (fst points.[j] - fst points.[k]) 
            else Polynom.One)
        |> List.fold (*) Polynom.One
    indizes |> List.sumBy (fun j -> Polynom.Const (snd points.[j]) * p j)
```

As you can see I used the same function and only replaces the argument `x` with `Polynom.X` and wrapped the constants approbiatley.

#### examples

and here are two examples (compare them to the [Wiki-Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Example_2) they should be right):

```
> LagrangeInterpolation.getPolynom 
    [|(1.0, 1.0); (2.0, 4.0); (3.0, 9.0)|] |> string;;
val it : string = "0.0X^0 + 0.0X^1 + 1.0X^2"

> LagrangeInterpolation.getPolynom 
     [| 1.0,1.0; 2.0,8.0; 3.0,27.0 |] |> string;;
val it : string = "6.0X^0 + -11.0X^1 + 6.0X^2"
```

#### complete code with helpers

the complete code for this inside a module is:

```
module LagrangeInterpolation =

    let private ofLen n cs =
        let l = List.length cs
        if l < n
            then cs @ List.replicate (n-l) 0.0
            else cs

    type Polynom = 
        Poly of float list with
        override p.ToString () =
            match p with
            | Poly coefs -> 
                System.String.Join (" + ", coefs |> List.mapi (fun i c -> sprintf "%AX^%d" c i))
        static member Const c = Poly [c]
        static member Zero = Polynom.Const 0.0
        static member One = Polynom.Const 1.0
        static member X = Poly [0.0; 1.0]
        static member (+) (Poly cs1, Poly cs2) =
            let m = max (List.length cs1) (List.length cs2)
            List.zip (ofLen m cs1) (ofLen m cs2)
            |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a+b)
            |> Poly
        static member (-) (Poly cs1, Poly cs2) =
            let m = max (List.length cs1) (List.length cs2)
            List.zip (ofLen m cs1) (ofLen m cs2)
            |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> a-b)
            |> Poly
        static member (*) (f : float, Poly cs2) : Polynom =
            cs2
            |> List.map (fun c -> f * c)
            |> Poly
        static member private shift n (Poly cs) =
            List.replicate n 0.0 @ cs |> Poly
        static member (*) (Poly cs1, p2 : Polynom) : Polynom =
            cs1
            |> List.mapi (fun i c -> Polynom.shift i (c * p2))
            |> List.sum
        static member (/) (Poly cs1, f : float) : Polynom =
            cs1
            |> List.map (fun c -> c / f)
            |> Poly

    let getPolynom (points : (float * float)[]) =
        let indizes = [0..points.Length-1]
        let p j = 
            indizes
            |> List.map (fun k -> 
                if k <> j 
                then (Polynom.X - Polynom.Const (fst points.[k]))
                      / (fst points.[j] - fst points.[k]) 
                else Polynom.One)
            |> List.fold (*) Polynom.One
        indizes |> List.sumBy (fun j -> Polynom.Const (snd points.[j]) * p j)
```

#### remarks

For better output you should probably add some simplifications (for example `Poly [1.0;0.0] -> Poly [1.0]`) and improve the `ToString` method but I'm sure you can handle ;)

Comment: Thanks, but want the function itself, like, I want to be able to see somewhere for example that the function of points (a,b,c) is x^2 - 2x + 4

Comment: so you want a symbolic representation or rather you want the coefficients? (I guess you want the representations of the langrangian interpolations - in your sample `a`, `b` and `c` are unrelated to the polynom itself) - you'll have to give me some time for that, but I will try to include this as well

Comment: @gabandre I hope this is what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help and effort. I didn`t imagined it could be so complex

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a function that is *partial*, i.e. it is undefined on some of its inputs, then there are generally two ways to deal with this. One option is to use `option<'T>` type and wrap the correct result in `Some` or return `None` when the value is undefined. For example:

```
let safeDivide a b =
    if b = 0 then None else Some(a / b)
```

The caller than has to pattern match on the result (or use something like the [Maybe computation builder](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions)) which makes calling the function harder, but you have full control over how the error is handled.

The other option is to throw an exception. This happens automatically for integer division, but you could write something like this:

```
let safeDivide a b =
    if b = 0 then invalidArg "b" "Division by zero!"
    a / b
```

This is a bit easier to write, but you need to be aware of the behavior and handle the exceptions correctly.

Comment: +1 for the good answer - but I think @gabandre means "incomplete" in the sense that he only knows some points on it's graph - let's see

Comment: @CarstenKönig Oh, I see!

Comment: :D - I think he wants the actual lagrangian (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html) - and it's easy to implement - I think we can do it rather easy in F# (should only take a few lines ;) ) - but I wanted to wait till we get some kind of confirmation

Comment: @CarstenKönig Your interpretation skills on this question are a lot better than mine! I think what you're saying makes sense.